# In jquery, what is the best selector to capture change event of a input with a class but also inside a ul with a certain Id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<ul id="tree3" class="checkboxTree[1] checkboxTree">
 <li class="collapsed">
 <li class="collapsed">
 <li class="collapsed">
 <li class="collapsed">
 <li class="collapsed">
 <span>
 <input class="checktree" type="checkbox" value="19" fullname="MyName">
```

and i am trying to capture the change event of the checkbox.  This works fine:

```
$(".checktree").change(function () {
    UpdateSelectedList();
});
```

but I need to scope it as i have multiple ".checktree" on the page.  I tried doing this:

```
$("#tree3 > .checktree").change(function () {
    UpdateSelectedList();
});
```

or this:

```
$("ul#tree3 > .checktree").change(function () {
    UpdateSelectedList();
});
```

but they didn't seem to fire.  Can someone suggest what is wrong with the above selectors ?

Comment: What does your HTML really look like? What you have in your question is an invalid mess.

Comment: @mu - its generated from the jquery checkboxtree plugin http://checkboxtree.googlecode.com/svn/tags/checkboxtree-0.5.2/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `>` element in selector means child of.  Since your `.checktree` isn't a direct child of `#tree3`, it's not working.  Try `#tree3 .checktree` or `#tree3 > li > span > .checktree` if you want the exact match.

[jQuery Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) vs [jQuery Descendent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)